# Twilio remove page limit to fetch record as a single csv

Tags: java, get, postman, twilio, rest

```
https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/AC******************/Calls.csv?To=+18000000000&StartTime>=2021-01-01&EndTime<=2021-02-01&PageSize=1000
```

I don't want to limit the records to 1000 per page, if i don't specify PageLimit it takes default as 50 per page.
What modifications are to be done to get all records without a paze size limit as a single csv .

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

The `PageSize` limit of 1000 is to protect our API and database from long running requests.  You cannot request more than 1000 API results at a time with the [calls resource](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/api/call-resource). Instead, you have two options.

You can make multiple calls to the API to request all of your calls. Each API response returns the list of calls as well as pagination information. If you take a look at [the example response when you request a list of calls](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/api/call-resource?code-sample=code-read-multiple-call-resources-and-filter-by-call-status-and-phone-number&code-language=curl&code-sdk-version=json) then you will see the pagination looks like this:

```json
{
  "calls": [
    // The call objects
  ],
  "end": 1,
  "first_page_uri": "/2010-04-01/Accounts/ACXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/Calls.json?Status=completed&To=%2B123456789&From=%2B987654321&StartTime=2008-01-02&ParentCallSid=CAXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&EndTime=2009-01-02&PageSize=2&Page=0",
  "next_page_uri": "/2010-04-01/Accounts/ACXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/Calls.json?Status=completed&To=%2B123456789&From=%2B987654321&StartTime=2008-01-02&ParentCallSid=CAXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&EndTime=2009-01-02&PageSize=2&Page=1&PageToken=PACAaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa0",
  "page": 0,
  "page_size": 2,
  "previous_page_uri": "/2010-04-01/Accounts/ACXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/Calls.json?Status=completed&To=%2B123456789&From=%2B987654321&StartTime=2008-01-02&ParentCallSid=CAXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&EndTime=2009-01-02&PageSize=2&Page=0",
  "start": 0,
  "uri": "/2010-04-01/Accounts/ACXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/Calls.json?Status=completed&To=%2B123456789&From=%2B987654321&StartTime=2008-01-02&ParentCallSid=CAXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&EndTime=2009-01-02&PageSize=2&Page=0"
}
```

You can use the `next_page_uri` to request the next page of results until they are exhausted.

Alternatively, there is a [Bulk Export API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/usage/bulkexport) available. The Bulk Export API allows you to create jobs that gather and export calls, messages, and other resources. When the data is ready to download the API will send a webhook or an email with the data.

Comment: Okay . Thank You .I shall try it .